# Getting Invalid JWT token. The token is expired

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-integration

I just created an App today and now it got successfully working but all of sudden i am getting a message saying that "Invalid JWT token. The token is expired".

What should i do refresh this token.

I created an app using Sharepoint Online app creation by following below blog: https://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, you could renew a Shared Secret for an app without changing the Client ID according to the article below.

[Replace an expiring client secret in a SharePoint Add-in](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/replace-an-expiring-client-secret-in-a-sharepoint-add-in)

And you also could update an expiring Client Secret according to the article below.

[Updating an expiring Client Secret (JWT token).](https://emgage.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002472513)

Answer (score 0):

If you have created an App that means you have the ClientId and Secret you can use this library [`sp-devops`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sp-devops) to get to access API's

```
$ sp-devops --accesstoken # will generate a new access token everytime it expires.
```

Check in detail: https://medium.com/@joy.blanks/frontend-frameworks-inside-microsoft-sharepoint-e7694aa43c5d

Comment: Thank you Joy for the response. Can you please let me know where should i mention above script. Let me tell you what i did is by following the blog posted in question i generated a token and that token i using in servicenow to integrate with Sharepoint. Now the script line which you gave honestly i dont have idea what is if you can please help me out that would be great.